# How to hide a div if an URL cannot reached?

Tags: javascript, url, html

I have integrated a Twitter feed into a website, if the end location (presumably `http://twitter.com/something`) cannot be reached, the feed does not display. This is ideal, however I have a title div placed directly above the feed which remains visible regardless of whether the feed is displayed on the page or not.

Is it possible to prevent the div (`#title`) from displaying if a URL cannot be reached? I've found JavaScript snippets which look to hide a div based on the URL of the file being viewed, but this doesn't seem to work in my situation.

HTML:

```
  <div id="title">
    <h3>Latest Tweets</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="twitter_update_list">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js">  
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/SW_Trains.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=3">
    </script>
  </div>
```

Many thanks in advance. I understand that this may not be possible with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
<div id="title" style="display:none;">
 <h3>Latest Tweets</h3>
</div>

<div id="twitter_update_list">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js">  
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/SW_Trains.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=3">
 </script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function(){

  var tdata = jQuery('#twitter_update_list').html().length;

  if(tdata > 0)
  {
     jQuery('#title').css('display','block');
  }
  else
  {
     jQuery('#title').css('display','none');
  }
 } 

</script>
```

May be it helps to you.

Comment: Hi Bharat, thank you for taking the time to respond. This doesn't seem to work for me, should I declare any 'display' attributes on either of the divs? I tried disconnecting from the internet to simulate the situation, and it turns out both '#twitter_update_list' and '#title' are present.

Comment: @HeyRustyjames you add like this <div id="title" style="display:none;">

Comment: I tried that, but as expected when you argue that the title div is 'display: none;' it doesn't display even when Twitter feed has content in it. I don't know much JS, but I would have thought your solution needs to include an 'else' statement to display the div when the feed **isn't** empty?

Comment: @HeyRustyJames now check my answer and try.

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck. It now displays the title div when content is present, but it doesn't hide the div when the feed is empty. I'm wondering whether the answer lies in the 2nd and 3rd line of the script. Again, I don't know much but I would assume 'tdata' or '.text()' isn't targeting the content in the right way. Sorry, this is more painful than it's worth.

Comment: @HeyRustyJames please check now my answer. i tested it on my system.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. The updated answer works!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sth like

```
var divContent = document.getElementById('twitter_update_list');
if (NOT divContent) {
    //no content detected
    document.getElementById('title').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}
```

This is untested and I don't know if it works. You will have to create a function which will be executed when the page has completely loaded. Maybe sth like:

```
window.onload = function(){
  // your code...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Xavjer, but I'm afraid I don't know JS well enough to be able to create a function. Still learning!

Answer (score 0):

After load make a function that tests the content of the div that would hold the content. If is empty just hide whatever you need to hide.